# ERROR: 500048: Inappropriate authentication when running adtool to retrieve a user's attributes

Tags: active-directory, bash, authentication, powerbroker

I have an Ubuntu server that is joined to an AD domain via PBIS-Open

I am running a query using adtool (/opt/pbis/bin/adtool) to query for a user's attribute.

The problem is that whenever I run this command with any system user, I keep receiving this error message

```
ERROR: 500048: Inappropriate authentication
```

However, when I run the same command using an AD user **who has previously logged in to that server**, I get the results normally without any errors.

Any ideas how can I run that command with any user successfully?

Comment: you need to authentication to the directory in order to make ldap queries - why would a local system user have access to AD?